# Value of variable is not being changed (Ajax validation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been dealing with these issue for a few days, and I can't seem to be able to fix it on my own. I've already asked a question here on Stack regarding this, however I've been told this is resolved by using callback functions. I've done exactly that but the variable inside the callback still isn't changed.

I am using abide validation that is built into the Foundation framework, and I am trying to have my own custom validator for checking if an email already exists in our database. Everything works, even the console.log returns the correct results, but the variable value is not changed from false to true. **Only check the code from emailVerification downwards.**

Thank you for your help.

```js
$(document).foundation({
  abide : {
    live_validate : false, // validate the form as you go
    validate_on_blur : false,
    patterns: {
       positive_price: /^\+?[0-9]*\,?[1-9]+$/,
     },
     validators: {
         positiveNumber: function(el, required, parent) {
          var value  = el.value.replace(/,/, '.'),
              valid = (value > 0);
          return valid;
        },
        emailVerification: function (el, required, parent) {
          var email = el.value,
          ajax = 1,
          valid = false;

          function checkServer(callback) {
            $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "/check.do?action=userEmailAvailable",
                  data: "userEmail1=" + email + "&ajax=" + ajax,
                  success: callback
            });
          }

          checkServer(function(data) {
            if (data.result == 1) {
                console.log(data.result + "does not exist");
                valid = true;
              } else {
                console.log(data.result + "already exist");
                valid = false;
              }
          });

          return valid;

        }

       }
     }
});
```

Comment: Value of `valid` is initialized as `false` which is being returned as your script will not wait to return valued after `http request` hence you wil be getting `false` in all the situations. You need to use [`promise`](https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/promises-guide)  in such cases.

Comment: @RayonDabre hmm I was told I could do this with either deffer, callback or promises. So Promise is the only way?

Comment: Just check with the library you are using whether they have any approach for remote validation ?

Answer (score 1):

the valid that you declare in positiveNumber function is locally scoped to that function only. the next time you attempt to access it outside the function you actually create a global var called valid

Comment: Hey, I actually define another valid in emailVerification. As I've said, only code from emailVerification downwards is relevant. Thank you anyway for your contribution.

Comment: right, but being as how it has no var key word all the other functions that reference valid without var are accessing the same global valid.

Answer (score 1):

$.ajax runs asynchronously. You function returns "valid" before callback function is called. You can try running your ajax request synchronously or you need to add logic in your callback function that updates "valid" when it's called

[How to create sync ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)

Add validation function to you callback

```
checkServer(function(data) {
        if (data.result == 1) {
            console.log(data.result + "does not exist");
            valid = true;
          } else {
            console.log(data.result + "already exist");
            valid = false;
          }
        DoCoolValidation(valid)
      });
```

If you are sure that your server validation is fast enough you can do

```
    function Validate(dataToSend) {
return JSON.parse($.ajax({
    url: '/check.do?action=userEmailAvailable',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: dataToSend,
    async: false
}).responseText);}
```

And use it:

```
valid = Validate("userEmail1=" + email + "&ajax=" + ajax);
```

---

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) post. It can help

Comment: Any ideas how I might to that? Please, I've been messing with this for a few days now.

Comment: I get DoCoolValidation is undefined, where do I define it?

Comment: Oh, it's just a function that does your validation. You should create it in root

Answer (score 1):

As many answered, you need async validation and [Abide does not support this](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/35127-asynchronous-validation-with-abide).

I would suggest you use the excellent Parsley.js library which supports async validators through its [Remote plugin](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#remote)

Comment: So I cannot do this with any of the proposed solutions? I have to change a loot of pages if i now decide to swap abide with parsley, although it does look promising.

Comment: Well, everyone is right on the async nature of your problem but none of the proposed "solutions" are going to help you hack Abide to make it work.

Comment: I don't think you should change a lot of pages since Abide and Parsley both works with regular HTML5 form validation like `required` and `pattern` attributes